# FileNotFoundException with 404 status for valid URL on HTTP GET request

Tags: java, android, http

I have the following code to perform a GET request on the following URL:

```
http://rt.hnnnglmbrg.de/server.php/someReferenceNumber
```

However, here is my output from Logcat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://rt.hnnnglmbrg.de/server.php/6
```

**Why does it return 404 when the URL is clearly valid?**

Here is my connect code:

```
/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request that returns base64 data from the server
 * 
 * @param ref
 *            The Accident's reference
 * @return The base64 data from the server.
 */
public static String performGet(String ref) {
    String returnRef = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL + "/" + ref);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        returnRef = builder.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnRef;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested with any reference number in Desktop browser. Will that provide any details from server.

Comment: Yes and it returns fine.

Comment: 404 is not about valid of url or not, it's about the URL is not found, which is responded by the http server.

Comment: But how can it not be found if it works in my desktop browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you request the URL, it actually return HTTP code `404` which mean not found. If you have control to the PHP script, set the header to `200` to indicate file is found.

[image]

Comment: @paranoid-android The exception is because the response code. You can test it by point the URL that return status `200`.

Comment: How did you test it like that?

Comment: Pau Kiat Wee is absolutely correct. The exception which is generating is because of wrong status code at url. +1

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `404`, as said above. To avoid an exception, try something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect () ; 
int code = con.getResponseCode() ;
if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)
{
    // Handle error
}
else
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, it just changes it. Not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust what you see in your browser. Always try to mimic your request using something like curl, and you'll clearly see that you're getting an HTTP 404 response code.

java.net will translate the HTTP 404 code to a FileNotFoundException

```
curl -v  http://rt.hnnnglmbrg.de/server.php/4
* About to connect() to rt.hnnnglmbrg.de port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 217.160.115.112... connected
* Connected to rt.hnnnglmbrg.de (217.160.115.112) port 80 (#0)
> GET /server.php/4 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: rt.hnnnglmbrg.de
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2012 07:34:55 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host rt.hnnnglmbrg.de left intact
* Closing connection #0
0
```

From the javadocs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

*Returns the error stream if the connection failed but the server sent useful data nonetheless. The typical example is when an HTTP server responds with a 404, which will cause a FileNotFoundException to be thrown in connect, but the server sent an HTML help page with suggestions as to what to do.*